# sensor sampling frequency of samsung android phones

Tags: android, accelerometer

What is the sensor sampling rate of samsung galaxy pop android phone in SENSOR_DELAY_GAME.From where did I get this information?I want to use the accelerometer sensor.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12):

According to ICS [sourcecode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/hardware/SensorManager.java)

```
case SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST:
    delay = 0;
    break;
case SENSOR_DELAY_GAME:
    delay = 20000;
    break;
case SENSOR_DELAY_UI:
    delay = 66667;
    break;
case SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL:
    delay = 200000;
```

those are in μs so `SENSOR_DELAY_GAME` would be 20ms or 50Hz

It still depends on your Hardware etc. So you might want to measure it to verify that.

Comment: Is this rate same for every hardware ?I am using samsung smartphone.

Comment: Not exactly the same. Each sensor requires a different time to read the current state. After that is done the delay is used in addition. So the actual delay between callbacks is at least `hardwareConstraints + delay + softwareDelay`. That `softwareDelay` would be the time it takes to get the values from the sensor-read code to your callback code. It might also be the case that the hardware vendor adjusted the delay values or that those values are different in previous versions of Android.

Comment: Is it possible to moderate the frequency? As in, if GAME frequency is 50Hz, can we moderate it to 25 Hz? Or if FASTEST frequency is approx 400Hz, can we moderate to 100 Hz? Does it need to be done in terms of setting delay value?

Comment: @TheTank Not really. There are only those fixed modes. But you could use a faster than needed mode and throw away every 2nd value for example. Or calculate the average of N values to reduce input to the desired rate. Or just   store the latest value and whenever the game needs an update,eg each game loop iteration, it takes that value, whether it was updated with fresh sensor data 0 or 20 times since the last iteration